# E11000 duplicate key error index: myproject.users.$username_1 dup key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to add a new user to the database, one time adds, and the second one gives an error

{ MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: myproject.users.$username_1 dup key: { : null }
    at Function.create (D:\projects\myproject\server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:43:12)
    at toError (D:\projects\myproject\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:149:22)
    at coll.s.topology.insert (D:\projects\myproject\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\collection_ops.js:859:39)
    at D:\projects\myproject\server\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:532:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
  driver: true,
  name: 'MongoError',
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  errmsg:
   'E11000 duplicate key error index: myproject.users.$username_1 dup key: { : null }',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }

[image]

users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const validateRegisterInput = require('../../validation/register');

const User = require('../../models/User');

// @route   GET api/users/test
// @desc    Tests users route
// @access  Public
router.get('/test', (req, res) => res.json({msg: 'Users Works'}));

// @route   POST api/users/register
// @desc    Register user
// @access  Public
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const {errors, isValid} = validateRegisterInput(req.body);

  // Check Validation
  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  User.findOne({email: req.body.email}).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      errors.email = 'Email already exists';
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    } else {

      const newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
      });

      bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
          console.log(333)
          if (err) throw err;
          newUser.password = hash;
          newUser
            .save()
            .then(user => res.json(user))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Users.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Drop your index `User.dropIndex({ username: 1})`

Comment: What do you mean ? I don't understand (

Comment: TypeError: User.dropIndex is not a function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem, I don’t know why, but there were index fields in the database, I deleted them and it all worked
[image]